# Kubuntu with AMD Sempron

Tags: system-installation, usb-creator

I want to install Kubuntu on a USB stick to run on my Acer Aspire 1362WLD laptop with an AMD Sempron 2800+ chip (I think it is 32-bit), also running Windows XP Home - which ISO/torrent should I use?

Many thanks for this, SirCharlo. After a few tries I think I am making progress, but I'm not there yet. (I have edited my first post, as I haven't quite got the hang of this forum yet.)

Using Windows I downloaded and saved **kubuntu-2.04.1-desktop-i386.iso** followed by **Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.1.1.exe**. I ran the latter file, entering the former at the red-letter prompt.

Entering Bios setup, the boot option order was Hard Drive, Floppy Drive, CD Rom/DVD Drive and Network Boot. There was no option for USB drive, so I just moved Hard Drive from top to bottom and saved the setup.

On rebooting a black screen appears with two messages:

> Error E61 Media test failure - check cable
>   PXE MOF Exiting Intel PXE Rom
>   This is soon replaced by a choice of Windows XP and Ubuntu

Selecting the latter, a black screen appears with error messages including something like :

```
Error prefix is not set 
Error No such device /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
Error No such device /ubuntu/install/boot/grub.config
```

This is soon replaced by a message:

```
Minimal Bash-like editing is supported...
grub> [flashing cursor]. This is as far as it gets.
```

Have I gone wrong somewhere? If not, do I need to try the alternative methods describes in
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick such as the PloP Boot manager, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the regular 32-bit Kubuntu ISO (the recommended download) from the [official Kubuntu download page](http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/download).

Instructions on creating a Live USB can be found on the above-linked site, and are reproduced below, for your installation-media-creating pleasure!

---

> #### Burning a CD or creating an install USB stick
>
> Kubuntu can be installed from a recordable CD (or DVD) or from an USB stick. Then it can be used as a regular operation system, or as a Live image which you can install Kubuntu from. For more information, see [Burning ISO Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) and [Installation From USB Stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) from the Ubuntu Community Documentation website.

---

Personally, I prefer using [LiLi](https://www.linuxliveusb.com/) to create bootable USBs. I've always had more success with that than with Unetbootin or anything else.

It's really simple to use, and you can't go wrong.

[image: LiLi]

---

Now, to setup your BIOS to boot up from your USB key, follow these steps, taken from [here](http://www.resetwindowspassword.com/how-to-set-bios.html).

> - Boot with the USB flash frive connected, and enter the BIOS setup.
> - Navigate to the Boot order screen, which may look similar to the one below.
>
> [image: Boot order screen]
>
> - Hard drive, floppy drive, and optical drive will be listed on this screen, and the listed order of them is the boot order of your
>     computer.
> - Choose `Hard Drive` if you want to set the computer to boot from your USB drive, as it is probably detected by your BIOS as a hard disk, not a removable drive..
> - Change the boot order of the hard drives. Choose `Hard Drive` first and then move your USB flash drive up in the list to make sure it's first. The boot order can usually be changed with the <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> keys.
>
> [image: Hard drive order]>
>
> - Finally, save the changes to the BIOS setup by locating and choosing the
>     `Exit Saving Changes` (or similarly worded) option. This can usually be accomplished by hitting <kbd>F10</kbd>.
>
> [image: Save changes]

---

Reboot your computer once it has been set up to boot from your USB flash drive, and you should be good to go! You'll be well on your way to installing your favorite Linux distribution.

Comment: Many thanks for this. After a few tries I think I might me getting there.

Comment: Great! Please upvote or accept the answer if it helped; it'll help clean up the site. Thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not there yet. I have edited my first message - please see

Comment: How about now @DenisRSmith?

Comment: Sadly not. LiLi seemed a little faster than Universal, which I tried before, but I still got the same dialogue and error messages as quoted in my first message. I changed the bios boot order several times with no further success. I suspect that some bash code needs to be entered into a boot file, which I could do using Windows Notebook on the laptop, or using Kubuntu on my dual-boot desktop - but I wouldn't have a clue what code to enter or in which file!

Comment: An update: I re-read your last post, so hit return on the hard disk boot option in bios, and found that I could indeed put my USB above the internal hard drive in a sub-menu. This gives a much more promising result. A dark blue screen announces Kubuntu 12.04 and gives options for persistent mode, live mode, install, memory test and file integrity test, and further options on F-keys such as help (which appears substantial) and accessibility. The first three options lead to a blank magenta screen, then error messages about WLAN and Plug&play, ending with a blank cyan screen.